# Water tank and Spout

Tags: equipment

I am trying to use a coffee machine water tank for a different project. The problem is, I am unable to find a water spout for the tank because of which I cannot pump the water out of it.

How does this work in a coffee machine? What kind of a part is it? and how do i find it?

If I were to put this question in a better way, How does the water tank couple to the pump and how do I find that part?

Thank you for your input.

EDIT: You can use this tank as a reference
[https://www.amazon.com/DeLonghi-7313228241-Delonghi-WATER-TANK/dp/B0166HQBTE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0166HQBTE)

EDIT2: So the product that I am looking for is basically a Valve lifter. But I cannot seem to find these for the water tanks I want to use. Is the mechanisme different for bigger machines?

Comment: I believe most coffee machines utilize pressure to suck water out of tanks.